# Pulling Information from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON string:

```
var txt= '{“group”: [
    {“family1”: {
            “firstname”:”child1”,
            “secondname”:”chlid2”
    }},
    {“family2”: {
            “firstname”:”child3”,
            “secondname”:”child4”
    }}
]}';
```

I'm having difficulty pulling out information such as "child1". I'm sure if it is just a syntax problem, or I'm not doing it correctly. I've tried doing this:

```
alert (group[0].family[0].firstname);
```

But I'm getting nothing....

Comment: That’s not valid JSON – note the “smart quotes”. Also, you can’t have unescaped newlines in a JavaScript string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see something wrong, and I'm not sure if you notice it.

```
“family2”
```

Those are fancy Unicode quotes. Computers don't do well with those quotes. Replace them with standard ASCII (Latin1) quotes – i.e. `"` – and then this should work:

```
var myobj = JSON.parse(txt);
alert(myobj.group[0].family1.firstName);
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for thanks! Apparently it was the quotes messing me up

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are u sing a JSON string and not just a JSON object?

Assuming you've already parsed the string into a JSON object, you are referencing a `family` array that does not exist.  You have `family1` and `family2` so `family[0]` does not exists.

You would need to do this: `parsedJson.group[0].family1.firstName`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to convert your string to object first. Do that with `JSON.parse()` function that takes string as argument. and returns JavaScript object frow which you can then pull your info:

```
var info = JSON.parse( txt );
alert( info.group[0].family1.firstname );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, the string you are using isn't closed. In Javascript, strings have to be on a single line.

Second, I would recommend writing it as a JSON object, rather than as a string. You can convert a string to an object, however.

Anyway, here is an example that shows what you want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/vB9AP/

```
var txt= {"group": [
{"family1": {
        "firstname":"child1",
        "secondname":"chlid2"
}},
{"family2": {
        "firstname":"child3",
        "secondname":"child4"
    }}
]};

alert( txt.group[0].family1.firstname );
```